# Using Odoo as a database for QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is it possible to link an Odoo database (CRM) into GGIS? I have an online Odoo Studio account with lots of data including long/lat data etc. Is it possible to link the Odoo database directly with Qgis or is that limited to PostGis etc?

Comment: the underlying database is a PostgreSQL database, so yes is the simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Odoo Studio, you probably have the Enterprise Version hosted on Odoo.sh. The [Odoo Cloud Platform FAQ](https://www.odoo.sh/faq#postgresql) mentions that you can't connect remotely to the database cluster.

However, if you replicate your instance locally or if you were hosting Odoo on-premise, you could connect to the database and read the tables in QGIS. However, be aware that writing to the database directly bypasses the ORM and all its security mechanisms, triggers or logic implemented in Odoo.

There should not be any problem reading from it though. So you could connect to it read-only and use the algorithm "Create points layer from table" in QGIS to create a layer from the table.

There is an addon for Odoo ([oca/geospatial](https://github.com/OCA/geospatial)) that enables real geospatial support in Odoo using PostGIS. You could then read tables directly from the Odoo database (without using an algorithm) since it stores an actual geometry field in the tables.